# static NSTableView cell in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, static-content

I wanted to create a static NSTableView just like the one available in IOS where w create a Static Cells in the xib. I want to do the same where in I have 5 cells to display. I read that `usesStaticContents`  in the TableView would do the job, but in my case it is not working. The view displays a blank screen. Could anybody let me know how do I achieve the following.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a day's struggle, I figured out how to display a static tableView Cell. All you need to do is in the XIB, add the identifier for all the cell's that you want to display and then implement the two required dataSource `numberOfRowsInTableView:` and `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`. You should now be able to display the Static TableView Cell.

Comment: I am trying to follow what you did here. I have 10 unique cells that I want to implement. Are you saying that I should create 10 different identifiers (one for each cell)? And what exactly are you doing in tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:?

Comment: Yes, for each cell, create different Identifier. In the `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` simply create a NSTableCellView object by calling the API `makeViewWithIdentifier`  for each index and return that object.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.